# Visual Basic 2019: ArgumentException thrown when trying to add a row to a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datasource

I am creating a database of students, and to add a student, I included a separate form. The separate form calls the sub AddStudent() in the main form. In the AddStudent() sub, I get an ArgumentException when I add a row to the table because apparently the table does not have any columns. I created the table in a global scope and the columns of the table were created in a sub that is handled by Form1.Load.

```
Public Class Form1

Private HiddenPages As New List(Of TabPage)
Dim StudentDB As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CreateTable()
    StudentDGV.DataSource = StudentDB
End Sub

Sub AddStudent(ByRef first As String, ByRef last As String, ByRef grade As String)
    StudentDB.Rows.Add(last, first, CInt(grade))
    StudentDGV.Refresh()
End Sub

Sub CreateTable()
    With StudentDB
        .Columns.Add("LastName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("FirstName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("GradeLevel", Type.GetType("System.Int16"))
    End With
End Sub
```

In case if it's necessary, StudentDGV is the DataGridView.

Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: `StudentBS.DataSource = StudentDGV`  The BindingSource is using the grid?  It always helps to tell us which line is throwing the exception.  You should only have to set the Source once, not every time you add a row.

Comment: I simplified it @LarsTech , but I still get an ArgumentException.

Comment: The posted code does not create an exception.  You are talking about separate forms. How are they referencing each other?

Answer (score 0):

> The separate form calls the sub AddStudent() in the main form. In the AddStudent() sub, I get an ArgumentException when I add a row to the table because apparently the table does not have any columns.

One scenario I can envision that will yield this set of conditions, is that the call from the *separate form* is running on a secondary thread and that the call is in the form of:

```
Form1.AddStudent("lastname", "firstname", "integer as string")
```

where `Form1` is the *default instance* property.  Default form instances are thread specific.  In referencing a default form instance from a secondary thread, a new instance of `Form1` will be returned.  Since this instance is never shown, the Form_Load event will not have been called on this instance, so the `CreateTable` method will not have executed on this instance.  That is why `StudentDB` does not have any columns.

If the above analysis is correct, you have a few issues to deal with.  Foremost, you should not be using a secondary thread to show this *separate form*.  I would recommend not using default instances in general.  Instead, you could pass this form a delegate to invoke instead to call back to the main form's `AddStudent` method.

---

Edit:

It just occurred to me that the above analysis assumed that an instance of `Form1` is shown.  If you have not shown yet, you would also be experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the grade column  with type Int16

```
.Columns.Add("GradeLevel", Type.GetType("System.Int16"))
```

But then you try to add an int32

```
StudentDB.Rows.Add(last, first, CInt(grade))
```

You can either change the column to int32 or convert the grade string to an int16.

Answer (score -1):

You want the `NewRow()` method. Also, there's no reason those method arguments should be `ByRef`. Leave them at the default `ByVal`. Remember, **`ByVal` still passes references**; it simply passes the value (a copy) of the reference.

```
Sub AddStudent(first As String, last As String, grade As String)
    Dim row = StudentDB.NewRow()
    row["LastName"] = last
    row["FirstName"] = first
    row["GradeLevel"] = CInt(grade)
    StudentDB.Rows.Add(row)
End Sub
```

Comment: He doesn't "need" the NewRow().  Rows.Add does have a ParamArray overload.  NewRow is probably preferred.

Comment: I still get an ArgumentException at the line `row("LastName") = last`